# UItabbarController more tabbar item controller tableView leaves some space at right side

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am using a `UITabBarController` where there are 13 tabs.

When I am switching to the more `tabBarItem` the `tableView` leaves some space at right side in the controller list `tableView`.

I have linked a screenshot for my issue.

[image: This is the screen shot of the simulator in iPad Air 2]

Comment: Check the auto layouts in more view controller in story board.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check  auto layout or auto resize of you app

but to access tableView of more screen you can use this

```
UITableView *moreTableView = (UITableView *)tabbarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view;
moreTableView.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: i have worked on adding ur code but its not working for me.